# Karatsuba algorithm v.s. "*" operator?

Tags: algorithm

Today, I heard of Karatsuba algorithm, a fast multiplication algorithm. I am curious that in which sense does this "fast" mean?

Normally, we consider a multiplication operation using * operator as O(1) when calculating the time complexity of a piece of code, and if it's always true, how come we have a faster algorithm with regard to asymptotic notation? Or * should not be considered O(1) when performed on very large numbers, where Karatsuba algorithm can be useful?

And in the machine level, compilers always do some optimization on *. For example, using bit-wise operations to multiply a number by 2^n. Does Karatsuba algorithm beat * in the actual running time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classical multiplication is O(n<sup>2</sup>), where *n* is the number of digits in the number being multiplied.

When measuring normal computer code, you're dealing with fixed-size (typically 32-bit or 64-bit) numbers, so that becomes O(1) (since the size doesn't change)

Once you start dealing with BigIntegers, this becomes very important.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm belongs to long numbers. Longer that the register size in CPU.
This is from Wikipedia:

> The Karatsuba algorithm is a fast multiplication algorithm. It was
>   invented by Anatolii Alexeevitch Karatsuba in 1960 and published in
>   1962. It reduces the multiplication of two n-digit numbers to at most 3 n^ (log_2 3) = 3 n^1.585 single-digit multiplications
>   in general (and exactly n^(log_2 3) when n is a power of 2).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this question is that the `*` operator as you call it isn't an algorithm.  It's completely left up to some combination the compiler (or interpreter) and the CPU to determine how it comes up with the answer.

<strike>I'm not sure where the claim that the using built-in multiplcation is O(1) but that can't be true unless there are some limitations to the input (perhaps such that N must be small enough to fit in a CPU register) or some lookup table is used.</strike>

As SLaks mentions when multiplication happens in the CPU (for most CPUs), the numbers are always the same size, either 32 or 64 bit. Even though the number 1 can be represented with a single bit, it still takes up 32 bits of space (in most implementations)

Big-O notation simply tells you that there exists a some size of input after which an a more efficient algorithm (in Big-O terms) will be faster than a less efficient one.

Bitshifting cannot be applied to all any arbitrary multiplication so while practically it's useful, algorithmically it can only be compared to other methods that only apply to multiplying by powers of two.

Most languages have a special type for handling numbers larger than 32-bits, and it might even be possible that when multiplying them using `*` the Karatsuba algorithm is being used.

Comment: I guess the overall point is that there are intersections between theory and practice but they're not the same thing.

Comment: Built-in multiplication would be O(1) since it's only defined for some fixed-width types. But of course, that makes O()-notation not applicable, strictly speaking.

Comment: @DanielFischer "since it's only defined for some fixed-width types"  The OP didn't specify a language, and there are language where the operator is defined for arbitrary sized numbers, for instance Python  (Not sure if it's arbitrarily sized, but just successfully multiplied 2 numbers with the `*` operator that are larger than 2^64)

Comment: I thought by built-in, the OP referred to the CPU. If it's built-in with respect to the language, that's of course something different. And yes, Python has arbitrarily large (well, for all practical purposes) numbers built-in.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's possible that's what the OP was thinking, however there was no mention of it in the question, and the `*` operator is defined at the language level not the CPU level, although in many cases it maps one to one with the CPU instruction.